# how check mdi child already running?

Tags: winapi, mdi, square

please help me.. i have a project use mdi application. my question is, how to check mdi child already running or not..? please help me..

Answer (score 2):

I use the following technique, but it requires a specific Sub for each Form type(I'm using VB.NET).  However I'm sure there could be a way to simplify this to handle all child forms with one sub

```
        Dim blExists As Boolean = False
        For Each f As Form In Me.MdiChildren
            If TypeOf (f) Is FormName Then
                f.Focus()
                blExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not blExists Then
            fAnalysis = New FormName
            fAnalysis.MdiParent = Me
            fAnalysis.Show()
        End If
```

The following sub works for all forms.

```
Private Sub ShowNewForm(ByVal frmName As Form)
        Dim blExists As Boolean = False
        Dim f as Form
        For Each f In Me.MdiChildren
            If f.Name Is frmName.Name Then
                f.Focus()
                blExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not blExists Then
            f = DirectCast(New Form, frmName.Type)
            fAnalysis.MdiParent = Me
            f.Show()
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you created the MDI window, you used [WM_MDICREATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644913(VS.85).aspx) right?  Well that message returns a window handle, You should save that handle somewhere so that you can refer to it if you want to find the window later or check to see if it exists.

```
MDICREATESTRUCT mci;
// fill out mci...
HWND hwndChild = (HWND) SendMessage(hwndMDI, WM_MDICREATE, 0, (LPARAM)(ULONG_PTR)&mci); 

// save hwndChild so that I can use it later.
```

Comment: Also consider using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx if you've "lost" the handle.